# How to deal with naked domains when using azure managed certificates

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I'm trying to use the recently announced (in preview) managed certificates for Azure app service. One of the limitations is that you can't get one for naked domains. eg.: you can get one for www.domain.com, but not domain.com.

In my (current) web.config, I'm redirecting from 'naked' to 'www' anyway using rewrite rules, so beeing limited to 'www' is not a real problem. However, as the redirect takes place at the web.config level, that is, after the request has hit the webserver, this is too late: when 'domain.com' gets hit and tries to redirect, the browser has already seen the insecure connection to the naked domain (depending on browser) will display a warning page.

So how is one supposed to do deal with the "naked" domains? No more redirects at all? Or are there other methods to do this besides web.config configurations? I did look, but did not find anything.

Comment: It took them over 4 years to implement, and they only got it half done.  :/

Comment: Unfortunately is the wrong half. Everyone is using naked domains nowadays.

Comment: For visitors in 2021 and beyond: this is now supported: https://azure.github.io/AppService/2021/03/02/asmc-apex-domain.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, after a *long* time, Azure finally supports this. One can simply use a managed cert for naked domains.

See here: https://azure.github.io/AppService/2021/03/02/asmc-apex-domain.html

Answer (score 4):

Adding to Jack's suggestions.

Currently, the preview offering only supports CNAME based validation. Thanks for the feedback and it is on our list of future improvements to consider however we do not have any ETA on this yet. So, request you to up-vote this feedback post on Uservoice- 
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/38981932-add-naked-domain-support-to-app-service-managed-ce

Alternatively, you may try to forward apex domains to subdomain such as www.

So based on your requirement, to redirect -
https://yourdomain.com -> https://www.yourdomain.com

If you are using App Service Domain, you can forward your domain by going to 'Advanced Management portal' of the domain resource.

[image: Advance Management Portal]

[image: Forwarding Domains]

[image: Forward to domain]

Comment: I'm unable to find the UI shown in the second and third pictures. The Advanced Management portal link redirects me to https://dcc.secureserver.net/domains

Comment: OK, I found it, there is a toggle next to the search bar on the domain list for simple view and Advanced view. Need to choose the rightmost icon for Advanced to show the extra toolbar in the 2nd pic

Answer (score 2):

In this scenario, I think a redirect is necessary.

We can get some clues from other international websites. For example: when I try to access `http://google.com`, actually I will get a `301` redirect which redirects me to `http://www.google.com`, and then I will get a `302` redirect which redirects me to `https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl`

[image]

So, as managed certificate does not support naked domain. I suggest you directly add your www subdomain to your web app. And then create managed certificate to that www subdomain.

And, finally, you can add 301 and 302 redirect rules in your DNS provider, which will ensure all requests to naked domain will be redirected to www subdomain.  This could be done in your DNS provider before your web app.

Answer (score 1):

So after some time trying things, here's how i ended up dealing with this:
- Using managed domain certificates for all hostname.Domain.tld names
- Using the letsencrypt script (from extensions) to get a cert for the naked domain

Once azure will provide certs for the naked domain, i will retire the script.